# Turning csvs into dataframes with a loop

Tags: python, loops, csv

Sample code

```
users = []
for files in glob.glob('/Users/*_dt*'):
  if files != glob.glob('*_dt*'):
    user_swims = pd.read_csv(files)
    print(users)
```

For the code above

I am trying to write a loop that will find the *_dt folder* to grab all the files that have _dt in the name once this happens, I wrote the loop to take the files it found and put them in a dataframe with the pd.read_csv command. This code puts all of the csv's it finds into one dataframe.

How should I write code to create a dataframe for each *csv* it finds? A one to one ratio.

Thanks
any tips on for loops and other settings to consider would be great.

Comment: What is the purpose of `if files != glob.glob('*_dt*'):`?

Comment: I guess it was unnecessary, the code will do the same thing without that line

Comment: Without that line, the code will do something. _With_ that line, it will do nothing.

Comment: ok i removed the line but do you know any way to create dataframes for each csv it finds?

Comment: You already created them. `user_swims` is a DataFrame. What exactly is your question?

Comment: for each file i wish to create a seperate dataframe, for example if theres 3 files with 1.csv,2.csv,3.csv i want to create each into their own df

Comment: You *do* do that. But youd discard every one except the last, because you do `user_swims = pd.read_csv(files)`, but you then you forgot to add `users.append(user_swims)`

Comment: could you give an example juanpa of where to add the code

Comment: Why on earth do you know how to create a dataframe, but do not know how to build a list? I strongly suggest you put aside all pandas stuff and read an elementary python textbook, where list construction would be on the first 100 pages.

Comment: my bad DYZ im learning but sample code would be wonderful and a great help